# File length always gives 0 while uploading file in android

Tags: java, android, file

In the following code file.length() always gives 0.  I am taking file from uploader in my Android App. I have set all file permissions and internet permission as well but still unable to get the length of the file so can not able to convert into Base64 and pass it to my webserive which decodes it using Base64_decode and saves the file in folder.

```
try {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Log.d("mypath",uri+"");
    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
    Log.d("Tn1",file.length()+"");
    //int size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()/1024));
    int size = (int)file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    //byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
    Log.d("mysize",size+"Pr");
    String encode = Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);
    //Log.d("Tn2",encode);
    String fileExtension
    = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
    Log.d("Tn",fileExtension);
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
    int indexStart = mimeType.indexOf("/");
    mimeType = mimeType.substring(indexStart+1);
    Log.d("minePrakhar", mimeType);
    if(mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("doc") 
        || mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf") 
        || mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("msexcel") 
        || mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") 
        || mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
    {
        new RetrieveFeedTask(encode, mimeType, file.getName()).execute();
        db.storeMessage(to_id, from_id + "", file.getName() + "", "file", localTime, "F", "ST", "R", "");
        chatItems.clear();
        dataFromDB();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(TestChat.this, "File Format is not Supported1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}catch (Exception e)`enter code here`{
    Log.e("minePrakhar123",e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeText(TestChat.this, "File Format is not Supported2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Does `file.exists()` return true? I would say not.

Comment: post your valuable solution here :)